# Java - Scanner not scanning after a certain number of lines

Tags: java, file-io, java.util.scanner, bufferedreader

I'm doing some relatively simple I/O in Java. I have a .txt files that I'm reading from using a  Scanner and a .txt file I'm writing to using a BufferedWriter. Another Scanner then reads that file and another BufferedWriter then creates another .txt file. I've provided the code below just in case, but I don't know if it will help too much, as I don't think the code is the issue here. The code compiles without any errors, but it's not doing what I expect it to. For some reason, charReader will only read about half of its file, then hasNext() will return false, even though the end of the file hasn't been reached. These aren't big text files - statsReader's file is 34 KB and charReader's file is 29 KB, which is even weirder, because statsReader reads its entire file fine, and it's bigger! Also, I do have that code surrounded in a try/catch, I just didn't include it.

From what I've looked up online, this may happen with very large files, but these are quite small, so I'm pretty lost.

My OS is Windows 7 64-bit.

```
        Scanner statsReader = new Scanner(statsFile);
        BufferedWriter statsWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(outputFile));

        while (statsReader.hasNext()) {
            statsWriter.write(statsReader.next());
            name = statsReader.nextLine();
            temp = statsReader.nextLine();
            if (temp.contains("form")) {
                name += " " + temp;
                temp = statsReader.next();
            }
            statsWriter.write(name);
            statsWriter.newLine();
            statsWriter.write(temp);
            if (! (temp = statsReader.next()).equals("-"))
                statsWriter.write("/" + temp);
            statsWriter.write("\t");
            statsWriter.write(statsReader.nextInt() + "\t");
            statsWriter.write(statsReader.nextInt() + "\t");
            statsWriter.write(statsReader.nextInt() + "\t");
            statsWriter.write(statsReader.nextInt() + "\t");
            statsWriter.write(statsReader.nextInt() + "\t");
            statsWriter.write(statsReader.nextInt() + "");
            statsWriter.newLine();
            statsReader.nextInt();
        }

        Scanner charReader = new Scanner(charFile);
        BufferedWriter codeWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(codeFile));   

        while (charReader.hasNext()) {
            color = charReader.next();
            name = charReader.nextLine();
            name = name.replaceAll("\t", "");
            typing = pokeReader.next();
            place = charReader.nextInt();
            area = charReader.nextInt();
            def = charReader.nextInt();
            shape = charReader.nextInt();
            size = charReader.nextInt();
            spe = charReader.nextInt();

            index = typing.indexOf('/');
            if (index == -1) {
                typeOne = determineType(typing);
                typeTwo = '0';
            }
            else {
                typeOne = determineType(typing.substring(0, index));
                typeTwo = determineType(typing.substring(index+1, typing.length()));
            }
        }
```

SSCCE:

```
public class Tester {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    File statsFile = new File("stats.txt");
    File testFile = new File("test.txt");
    try {
        Scanner statsReader = new Scanner(statsFile);
        BufferedWriter statsWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(testFile));
        while (statsReader.hasNext()) {
            statsWriter.write(statsReader.nextLine());
            statsWriter.newLine();
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Does it crap out always at the same place? Have you tried to simplify the text file to isolate the problem there? Have you simplified your Java code to isolate a smallest compilable sub-set that reproduces your problem? Do you use a debugger or a poor-man's debugger (`System.out.println` statements)?

Comment: Yes; the same place every time. Yeah, I made a loop that simply did codeWriter.write(charReader.nextLine()) while statsReader.hasNext(), and it did the same thing.

I am using Eclipse, and use both of those methods of debugging.

Comment: OK, good. Now if you can, I suggest that you create a very small compilable and runnable self-contained program (also known as an [SSCCE](http://SSCCE.org) as well as a small usable data file, and post both here so that we can reproduce your problem and try to modify your code to find a solution.

Comment: Okay. I made a separate program, and all I did was take the original statsFile, make a scanner read from it while hasNext() was true, and have a BufferedWriter write nextLine() in every iteration. The weird thing is that it still didn't get the whole file. It only got about 3/4s of the file this time.

Comment: Great, but we can't help you much without seeing your small program and the data file. I'm betting that there's a bug in the program, but can't say what based on the information you have presented so far.

Comment: Okay, I posted the SSCCE. The text file is a good 1,000+ lines, so that's why I didn't put it in.

Comment: Daniel, if possible put input files on pastebin. Perhaps there's a CTRL-D (EOF) in the input file.

Comment: @RC, Pastebin doesn't have the same guaranteed posterity as SO.  I think the code belongs here (it's trivial to copy).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a classic problem: You need to `flush` and `close` the output stream (in this case `statsWriter`) before reading the file.

Being buffered, it doesn't *actually* write to the file with ever call to `write`. Calling `flush` forces it to complete any pending write operations.

Here's the javadoc for [OutputStream.flush()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html#flush%28%29):

> Flushes this output stream and forces any buffered output bytes to be written out. The general contract of flush is that calling it is an indication that, if any bytes previously written have been buffered by the implementation of the output stream, such bytes should immediately be written to their intended destination.

Comment: This is something that even experienced developers do all the time. Only when our file craps out on us, this is one of the first things we look at because of how easy (and silly) of a mistake it is.

Comment: Thank you, but I'm not sure I understand. I flushed my BufferedWriters before reading/writing anything, but I got the same results. If I close them before I read/write, I get a compile error, since they're closed already. Are you saying that I need to use OutputStream instead of BufferedWriter? Also, the program stops when the hasNext() check returns false when it shouldn't, so I thought it was a problem with the Scanner.

Comment: Nevermind, I got it. I just changed the location of statsWriter.close() to before I declared the second set of Scanner/BufferedWriter. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

After you have written your file with your `statsWriter`, you need to call:

```
statsWriter.flush();
statsWriter.close();
```

or simply:

```
statsWriter.close();  // this will call flush();
```

This is becuase your are using a **Buffered** Writer, it does not write everything out to the file as you call the `write` functions, but rather in buffered chunks. When you call `flush()` and `close()`, it empties all the content it still has in it's buffer out to the file, and closes the stream.

You will need to do the same for your second writer.

Comment: `close()` do the `flush()`. see http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/Writer.html#close()